# How to use dynamic array of ids in raw query (rails + postgres)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have this code

```
Language.all.map{|l|[l.language, l.accounts.joins(:children).where("accounts.id IN (?)", @accounts.ids).uniq.count]}
```

I am trying to get this as output

```
[["eng", 5] ["span", 3] ["ital", 4] ... ]
```

I want to write it as a raw query.

I tried this,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select languages.language, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts where accounts.language_id = languages.id) from languages").values
```

but i need to pass accounts.ids dynamic.. like this

```
select languages.language, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts where accounts.language_id = languages.id AND (accounts.id IN (#{@accounts.ids})) from languages"
```

when i tried to pass `accounts.id IN #{@accounts.ids}` i am getting error
`(accounts.id IN ([2839, 284..` .. this should have been `IN (2839, 284..)` instead, it is taking array.

How to pass it dynamically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
"... accounts.id IN (#{@accounts.ids.join(',')})"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: nope. getting PG::syntax error. it takes the whole thing as string

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think you use Mysql.

Comment: Did you forgot a ")" in query ?

Comment: no. syntax error was not because of ')' .. but for strings (" 1, 2, 3 ... ")

Comment: I don't know where `"` come from? It should be `... accounts.id IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks man.. this helped.. what i did was i assigned whole Query to a variable and then i passed that variable inside `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(my_variable)` . and it worked :) but i am getting the array of result as string.. irrespecitive of column data  type.. like this `[["eng", "5"] ["span", '3"] ["ital", "4"] ... ]`. do you have any idea on that ?

Comment: I don't know why it return string in your case. Can you try  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query).rows` ?

Comment: same result .. getting string again

Answer (score 1):

The above 2 answers won't work if you are attempting to use an array of strings in a raw sql query. For a raw sql statement, you can use ActiveRecord's `sanitize_sql_array` method.

```
languages = ['eng', 'span', 'chin', 'ital']
base_query = "SELECT * FROM languages WHERE id IN (?)"
sanitized_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send :sanitize_sql_array, [base_query, languages]
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_query)
```

Comment: Very helpful, the change from an id to an uuid based system are tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where(id: @accounts.ids)` or `where("account.ids": @accounts.ids)` or `where("account.ids IN ?, @accounts.ids)`. I believe ActiveRecord should understand all of them.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions

Comment: yes. i know but i am trying to `map` another table records to get  in specific format `[[a, b] [c, d]]`. it results in low performance since there are large number of records.